# Calculate power of irrational number modulo of integer

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

There are very efficient ways to calculate powers of integers modulo an integer, one of them is implemented by the Python `pow` function.

I need to calculate something of the form `floor(num^k) % n` where `num` is irrational and `k`, `n` are integers.

For example how can I calculate the exact value `floor(π^k) % n` without actually calculating the huge value of `π^k`?

Thank you all brilliant people.

Comment: What does '%n'% mean? Is that modulo $n$?

Comment: Yes, this is common CS syntax for the least positive integer from the equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to speed up exponentiation modulo an integer $n$ (compared to general exponentiation) is using the fact that everything is integers to reduce the intermediate results modulo $n$. As the intermediate results in your case aren't integers, you can't do that.

The only transformation I can see of your expression is:
$$
\left\lfloor x^k\right\rfloor \pmod n
=\left\lfloor x^k\pmod n\right\rfloor
$$
and that doesn't make the computation any easier.